# How to sort a list of a custom class by a variable in that custom class? c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I was wondering how I would sort this list of mine.
Say i have class,

```
public class Foo
{
     public float bar;
}
```

And say I have list

```
List<Foo> sortedList = new List<Foo>();
```

And I want to sort Foo by its variable bar.
I am pretty sure i should use the linQ statement orderby, but i cant figure out how to sort by a variable in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort a list by calling `OrderBy`. Note this return an `IEnumerable<T>` to you will have to call `ToList()` to get a list again:

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(foo => foo.bar).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
var sorted =
        from foo in sortedList 
        orderby foo.bar ascending
        select foo;
```

Or:

```
var sorted = sortedList.OrderBy(foo => foo.bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it:

```
private List<ItemTotalsAcrossMonths> _itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList;
. . .
_itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList = _itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPurchases13).ToList();
```

I'm simply assigning the results of the sort back to the generic list; you need the "ToList()" at the end.